# What are the different ways of calculating dispersion constants?

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request, intermolecular-forces, dispersion-correction, one-topic-per-answer

There are many different dispersion corrections out there. The most famous is D3 [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3382344) (and the new D4 [[2]](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4993215)), but there's probably other approaches too. The dispersion energy can be written as:

$$
E_{\textrm{disp}} = -\sum_{ij}\sum_{6,8,10,\cdot \cdot  }\frac{C_n^{ij}f^{(n)}_{\textrm{damp}}(r)}{r^n},
$$

where the $C^{ij}_n$ coefficients are calculated differently depending on whether using D3 or D4, and the damping function $f$ can take on various forms.

**What are the other ways of calculating $C^{ij}_n$?**

---

[1] [*J. Chem. Phys.* 132, 154104 (**2010**)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3382344)
[2] [*J. Chem. Phys.* 147, 034112 (**2017**)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4993215)

P.S. For further discussion and overview, see [Grimme's](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.chemrev.5b00533) and [Tkatchenko's](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.chemrev.6b00446) review papers.

Comment: This answer by Geoff Hutchison might be helpful to you: https://materials.stackexchange.com/a/1120/5

Comment: Considering that this was one of the first questions on the site, and one of the highest voted, but still remains un-answered 40 days later, I tried to reach out to Geoff last week to answer this since he answered a similar question very very well already. With still no answer, I looked at the review article Geoff suggested. It addresses your question about what all the D corrections are. No one can possibly write all methods, and compare them, and then also answer your 3rd question question about the validity of D corrections in general, without basically re-writing that paper here.

Comment: As for comparing the different methods, you can look at Tabs. 4 & 9, or Fig 15 of [this review](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.chemrev.5b00533) which Geoff mentioned. It's also the review Stefan Grimme sent me by email yesterday, so his group doesn't have anything more recent. I did find a [review by a different group](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.chemrev.6b00446), which was published 1 yr later, & Tab 1 gives more comparison. This addresses your question about "comparisons". As for validity: you are right: none of these methods perfectly account for dispersion.

Comment: Excellent @NikeDattani! Thanks for all the comments and answer. It seems now that the original question was too broad indeed.

Comment: @NikeDattani By the way, both reviews are excellent!

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/12063/5, but that's about obtaining alpha(iw) rather than C6 directly.

Answer (score 9):

## 2007 (Becke & Johnson): XDM

XDM stands for "exchange-hole dipole moment" which is a model [introduced by Becke and Johnson in 2007](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2795701) for calculating dispersion constants. The formulas are as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!C_6    &= \frac{\alpha_i\alpha_j}{\mathcal{M}_i\alpha_j + \mathcal{M}_j\alpha_i} \mathcal{M}_i\mathcal{M}_j           \tag{1}\label{eq1} \\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!C_8    &=   \frac{\alpha_i\alpha_j}{\mathcal{M}_i\alpha_j + \mathcal{M}_j\alpha_i}\left(\frac{3}{2}\mathcal{M}_{1i}\mathcal{M}_{2j} + \frac{3}{2}\mathcal{M}_{2i}\mathcal{M}_{1j}\right)            \tag{2}\label{eq2}\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!C_{10} &=   \frac{\alpha_i\alpha_j}{\mathcal{M}_i\alpha_j + \mathcal{M}_j\alpha_i}\left(\frac{10}{5}\mathcal{M}_{1j}\mathcal{M}_{3j} + \frac{10}{5}\mathcal{M}_{3i} \mathcal{M}_{1j} + \frac{21}{5}\mathcal{M}_{2i} \mathcal{M}_{2j} \right), \tag{3}\label{eq3}
\end{align}$$

where for the system $x$: the dipole polarizability is $\alpha_{x}$ and the $l^{\textrm{th}}$ multi-pole moment is $\mathcal{M_{lx}}$, and $l=1,2,3$ correspond to the dipole, quadrupole, and octupole moments respectively.

Answer (score 5):

## 2009 (Tkatchenko−Scheffler) TS

The [Tkatchenko−Scheffler model](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.102.073005) for van der Waals interactions (vdW) defines the $C_6^{AB}$ parameters in an *ab-initio* fashion. In TS model the vdW energy $E_{vdw}$ is defined as,

\begin{equation}
E_{\text{vdW}} = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{A,B}f_{\text{damp}}\left(R_{AB},R^{0}_{A},R^{0}_{B}\right)C_{6}^{AB}R^{-6}_{AB} \tag{1} \end{equation}

where $R^0_{A}$ and $R^0_{B}$ are the vdW radii. The $C_6^{AB}$ parameter can defined by the Casimir-Polder integral exactly:

$$
C_6^{AB}=\frac{3}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha_{{A}}(i\omega)\alpha_{{B}}(i\omega)d\omega \tag{2} \label{eq:eq2}
$$

where $\alpha_{A/B}(i\omega)$ is the frequency-dependent polarizability of $A$ and $B$ evaluated at imaginary frequencies. The $\alpha_{A/B}(i\omega)$ can be replaced by an approximate $\alpha^1_{A/B}(i\omega)$, where $\alpha^1_{A}(i\omega)=\alpha^{0}_{A}/[1-(\omega/\eta_{A})^2]$. $\alpha^{0}_{A}$ is the static polarizability of $A$ and $\eta_{A}$ is an *effective frequency*. Simplifying \eqref{eq:eq2}, we get:

$$
C_6^{AB}=\frac{3}{2}[\eta_{A}\eta_{B}/(\eta_{A}+\eta_{B})]\alpha_{A}^0\alpha_{B}^0\tag{3}\label{eq:eq3}
$$

which after further simplification results in:

$$
C_6^{AB}=\frac{2C_6^{AA}C_6^{BB}}{[\frac{\alpha_{B}^0}{\alpha_{A}^0}C_6^{AA}+\frac{\alpha_{A}^0}{\alpha_{B}^0}C_6^{BB}]}\tag{4}
$$

$C_6^{AA}$ and $\alpha_{A}^0$ can be determined from [highly accurate benchmark calculations](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1779576).

Note: Here $C_6^{ij}\equiv C_6^{AB}$, $i\equiv A$ and $j\equiv B$

Comment: Hello, can help someone help me edit the equations here? The preview shows the equation format to be ok.

Comment: +1. I was waiting for someone else to answer! It was surprising that it took so long for someone to do it! I cannot see what's wrong with your equations. Maybe copy and paste mine and work from there.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a community page about "Dispersion methods in density functional theory" ? My field is condensed phase dynamics, and the consensus between molecular electronic structure calculations and bulk/interfacial simulations is actually not great, for example in the works of Angelos Michaelides: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4944633 & https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4754130 . I think a lot of users would benefit from such a page.

Comment: These are quite famous papers by Angelos. What do you mean by "community page"? By the way I was just looking again at your G16 question, I would like if you were to remove the answer or put it in the question. The answer has nothing to do with the question as far as I see. I understand that you were only responding to Cody's comment. I disagree with that comment.

Comment: @NikeDattani , I meant a "community wiki page" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts . BTW, I edited the G16 post.

Comment: Thank you for removing your answer on the G16 post. As for community wiki, we don't have any here yet, but we could start. Mind you, it [doesn't need to be a community wiki](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4222/2293), neither was [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/424/5).

Comment: @mykd Nike and I seem to have fixed the issue. Apparently, equation labels persist for the whole page and you happened to have the same equation labels as Nike for your first three expressions.