# What are some recent developments in density functional theory?

Tags: density-functional-theory, functional, one-topic-per-answer, algorithms, history

In the book [Materials Modelling Using Density Functional Theory: Properties and Predictions](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=FzOTAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Materials%20Modelling%20using%20Density%20Functional%20Theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHyL7svZvpAhXBF3IKHRdDDlMQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Feliciano Giustino, a timeline of milestones in DFT was given for achievements between 1964 and 1996:

$$\small\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Milestone} & \textbf{Researchers} \\ \hline
1964, 1965 & \text{HK Theorem/KS Formulation} & \text{Kohn, Hohenberg, Sham}  \\  
1972, 1973 & \text{Relativistic DFT} & \text{von Barth/Hedin, Rajapol/Callway} \\  
1980, 1981 & \text{Local Density Approximiation(LDA)} &\text{Ceperley/Alder, Perdew/Zunger} \\
1984 & \text{TDDFT} & \text{Runge, Gross}  \\
1985 & \text{First Principles MD} & \text{Carr, Parrinello}   \\  
1986 & \text{Quasiparticle Corrections} & \text{Hybertsen, Louie} \\  
1987 & \text{Density Functional Perturbation Theory} & \text{Baroni, Giannozzi, Testa}  \\  
1988, 1993 & \text{Toward Chemical Accuracy} & \text{Lee/Yang/Parr (1988), Becke (1993)} \\
1991 & \text{Hubbard Correction} & \text{Anisimov, Zaanen, Andersen} \\
1992, 1996 & \text{Generalized Gradient Approximation} & \text{Perdew/Burke/Ernzerhof} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Has there been any milestone after 1996, or not included in the above list?**

Please limit each answer to one milestone!

---

Since there's now so many answers that it takes a very long time to scroll down to a specific one, I Have created links for the milestones that have already been explained in an answer:

- [1993 (Becke) Hybrid Functionals](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1173/5)
- [1995 (Casida) TD-DFRT](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1284/5)
- [2004 (Yanai *et al.*) Range separation](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1188/5)
- [2005 (Bartlett) *ab initio* DFT](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1212/5)
- [2006 (Grimme) Double Hybrids](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1132/5)
- [2007 (Becke-Johnson) Dispersion correction](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1227/5)
- [2013 (Kim *et al.*) Density-corrected DFT](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1260/5)
- [2015 (Sun *et al.*) SCAN functional](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1192/5)

Comment: **Very** interesting question! What has Feliciano said about it? ;)

Comment: There's definitely been new work, such as "density-corrected DFT" by Eunji Sim and Kieron Burke, work on dispersion by Matthias Scheffler, work on excited states by Tom Ziegler, better potentials by Becke-Johnson, and Staroverov, double-hybrids by Stefan Grimme, however the timeline in the book might have stopped because it's too early to tell how much these things should be considered "milestones". The papers might be getting thousands of citations, but who knows what it will be like 20 years from now? 1996 does seem to be a long time ago though.

Comment: In the book the time frame was limited to 1965 to 2000 since post 2000 the field is evolving fast and it early to place recent developments in an historical perspective.

Comment: But I think we don't have to limit ourselves ;)

Comment: Exactly. So that's why I like this question :)

Comment: @NikeDattani. Shall we have a wiki answer so that everyone can contribute and we will have a single solid answer

Comment: @Thomas A Wiki answer would probably make the most sense for this question.

Comment: I think there is at least one error in the timeline. GGA was not introduced in 1996. The Becke88 functional is also a GGA.

Comment: It's a screenshot of the book from Google books

Comment: I understand that, but the author of the book made a mistake ;)

Comment: @Thomas now that there's a 250 point bounty, this question might get a lot of attention. The scanned material does not look so crisp, and might even violate copyright. I wonder if you can type the 10 milestones (only the title, year, and people involved... no need to type the paragraph explaining each milestone).

Comment: @Tyberius seem you did what I asked Thomas to do! Thank you for that! Shall we also correct the "error" which is that GGA functionals were introduced way before 1996 (Becke-88 for example)? 1996 is simply when PBE was first published?

Answer (score 29):

## 2006 (Grimme): Double hybrid functionals

The timeline of milestones you have given, includes a hybrid functional called B3LYP, which mixes a Hartree-Fock exchange functional with a GGA exchange-functional. [In 2006](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.2148954?journalCode=jcp), Stefan Grimme introduced what later became known as "double hybrid functionals", which not only mix the Hartree-Fock exchange functional with a GGA exchange-correlation functional, but also a many-body perturbation theory correction:

\begin{equation}
E_{\textrm{xc}}=\left(1-a_\textrm{x}\right)E_\textrm{x}^{\textrm{GGA}} + a_\textrm{x}E_\textrm{x}^{\textrm{HF}} + bE_\textrm{c}^{\textrm{GGA}} + cE_\textrm{c}^{\textrm{MBPT}}.
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

For the MBPT correction, Grimme used MP2 with the Kohn-Sham orbitals and single-excitations neglected. He tried various double hybrids, and the one that he finally recommended was obtained after setting b=1-c, and then using the Becke-88 functional for $E_\textrm{x}^{\textrm{HF}}$ and the LYP functional for $E_\textrm{c}^{\textrm{GGA}}$. He called this new functional **B2PLYP**.

By 2011 there existed several different double hybrid functionals made by various other groups, and [Goerigk and Grimme created](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2011/cp/c0cp02984j/unauth#!divAbstract) an enormous dataset by combining 30 test sets, containing a grand total of 841 relative energies involving 1218 total energies, and compared the performance of 47 functionals (2 LDA, 14 GGA, 3 meta-GGA, 23 Hybrid, 5 Double Hybrid) on this test suite. **Double hybrids were by far the most accurate family of functionals, with an estimated average error of only 1.8 kcal/mol:**

[image]

Comment: I think double hybrids were originally proposed by Truhlar and coworkers in Zhao, Y., Lynch, B., Truhlar, D. J. Phys. Chem. A 2004, 108, 4786..

Comment: @SusiLehtola I looked at Eqs 1 and 2 of that paper, and perhaps the $F^{\textrm{cor}}$ term resembles the last term of my Eq 1, but not quite. Grimme is using the KS orbitals to do essentially do MP2, which makes the calculation a lot more expensive, but can bring the total error down by quite a lot. The figure in my answer includes 5 double hybrids, but none of them are the 2004 one you're mentioning. I wonder why that is? It seemed this paper tried to be extremely comprehensive in including every relevant functional possible.

Comment: sure but AFAIK Truhlar's 2004 paper was the first to propose mixing in MP2 correlation, even though they appear to have used HF orbitals for that contribution. (Using KS orbitals for both parts should be cheaper, not more expensive!)

Answer (score 27):

## 2015 (Sun *et al.*): SCAN functional

[The SCAN meta-GGA functional](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.036402) is an extension of the popular PBE GGA [1] and the TPSS [2] and revTPSS [3] meta-GGAs, SCAN adheres to all 17 known exact XC constraints and is constructed to be almost exact for the noble gasses and jellium surfaces. Early evidence suggests that SCAN is more accurate than and of comparable efficiency to the aforementioned GGAs for crystal structure prediction [4-5], ab initio thermodynamics [6-7], and computational catalysis [8].

**References:**

[1] J. P. Perdew, K. Burke, and M. Ernzerhof,Phys. Rev. Lett.77, 3865 (1996).
[2] J. Tao, J. P. Perdew, V. N. Staroverov, and G. E. Scuseria,Phys. Rev. Lett.91, 146401 (2003).
[3] J. P. Perdew, A. Ruzsinszky, G. I. Csonka, L. A. Constantin,and J. Sun,Phys. Rev. Lett.103, 026403 (2009).
[4] H. Peng, Z.H. Yang, J.P. Perdew, and J. Sun, Phys. Rev. X 6, 041005 (2016).
[5] J.H. Yang, D.A. Kitchaev, and G. Ceder, Phys. Rev. B 100, 035132 (2019).
[6] E.B. Isaacs and C. Wolverton, Phys. Rev. Mater. 2, 063801 (2018).
[7] Y. Zhang, D.A. Kitchaev, J. Yang, T. Chen, S.T. Dacek, R.A. Sarmiento-Pérez, M.A.L. Marques, H. Peng, G. Ceder, J.P. Perdew, and J. Sun, Npj Comput. Mater. 4, 9 (2018).
[8] G. Sai Gautam and E.A. Carter, Phys. Rev. Mater. 2, 1 (2018).

Comment: Robert: Thanks for this first answer of yours! Welcome to the site and we hope to see much more of you here!! I have edited it to make it look a bit more compact. Are you able to give a simple formula for this functional, like in my answer? Also I'm not sure how important it is to include all these references. Refs 1-3 are just for the non-SCAN functionals which are not the focus of your answer (to keep things compact, I didn't cite Becke-88, or LYP, or even B3LYP, in my answer, even though they were mentioned). As for Refs 4-9, they are just examples of applications where SCAN was a success.

Answer (score 23):

## 2013: Density-Corrected DFT (DC-DFT)

The goal of Density-Corrected DFT (DC-DFT) is not only to get better accuracy but also to understand and correct the true error in the functional approximation.[1,2]
In any approximate density functional, the DFT error is
$\Delta E = \tilde E[\tilde n] - E[n]$
where $E$ and $n$ are exact functional and density while $\tilde {}$ represents approximate counterpart. 
Therefore, any density functional calculation has errors due to two causes: approximate functional and approximate density.
The true functional error is

$$\Delta E_F = \tilde E[n] - E[n] = \Delta E_{XC}[n]$$

and the remaining error is

$$\Delta E_D = \Delta E - \Delta E_F = \tilde E[\tilde n] - \tilde E[n]$$

called the density-driven error.
In most cases, $\Delta E_F$ dominates $\Delta E$ but, if DFT energy is density-sensitive, i.e., largely affected by density, $\Delta E_D$ is non-negligible and worth examining.

There is no guarantee that the HF density is closer to the exact density than DFT self-consistent densities, but HF-DFT[5,6] (DFT energy evaluated on HF density) is probably one of the simplest and most practical ways to perform DC-DFT.
Moreover, HF-DFT has shown to provide better results than standard approximations for various density-sensitive cases that are not spin contaminated including electron affinities, potential energy curves, spin gaps for coordination compound, and noncovalent interactions.[3,4]

1. M.-C. Kim, E. Sim, K. Burke, Phys. Rev. Lett., 111, 073003 (2013)
2. A. Wasserman, J. Nafziger, K. Jiang, M.-C. Kim, E. Sim, K. Burke, Annu. Rev. Phys. Chem., 68, 555 (2017)
3. Y. Kim, S. Song, E. Sim, K. Burke, J. Phys. Chem. Lett., 10, 295 (2019)
4. S. Vuckovic, S. Song, J. Kozlowski, E. Sim, K. Burke, J. Chem. Theo. Comp., 15, 6636 (2019)
5. P. Verma, A. Perera, R. J. Bartlett CPL, 524, 10-15, 2012
6. P.M.W. Gill, B.G. Johnson, J.A. Pople, M.J. Frisch, Int. J. Quant. Chem., 44,319 (1992)

Comment: +10. Welcome to the site Eunji! 감사합니다.

Comment: +100 I just stopped by to say how cool it is that Enuji Sim herself came to explain DC-DFT! Awesome work! :)
Signed, a fan of DC-DFT.

Answer (score 22):

## Dispersion corrected methods (2007/2010)

Lots of answers already, I would say the main ones are covered. However, in the spirit of the question, I don't think anyone has done dispersion corrections yet. So,

There are many levels of Dispersion corrected methods, but I would say the most common is from Grimme et al. in 2010 ([Grimme et. al. 2010 paper.](http://dns2.asia.edu.tw/%7Eysho/YSHO-English/1000%20WC/PDF/J%20Che%20Phy132,%20154104.pdf))

The energy correction is calculated as (taken from Frank Jensen's textbook)
\begin{equation}
   \Delta E_{\rm disp} = -\sum_{n=6} s_n \sum_{\rm AB} \frac{C_n^{\rm AB}}{R_{\rm AB}^n}f_{\rm damp}(R_{\rm AB})
\end{equation}
Further variations can also account for higher order $R^n$ dependance.

Becke & Johnson have also done work on more physics based corrections, more can be found at a different [question, here.](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/63/what-are-the-different-ways-of-calculating-dispersion-constants)

Comment: +1. Great to see a new user here! We hope to see much more of you! Just to point out: This formula for the dispersion energy goes back to at least 1930 (see papers by Fritz London, and the reason why the C6/r6 dispersion potential is often called the "London interaction"). Damping functions date back to decades before Grimme (see work of Scoles, Tang/Toonies, and others). Also, Grimme's 2016 review paper shows that M06 (not Grimme's DFT-D) is the most popular DFT method accounting for dispersion (according to number of citations, but this can sometimes be misleading).

Comment: You might find this interesting too: https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/63/5

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I can be the second or third person to work on something, but get 17K citations for it :)

Comment: I added a link to the other question, since they included the physics based approach of Becke

Comment: Well, the Becke-Johnson methods refer to specific ways of calculating the C6 and f_damp in the equation that you presented. Grimme's paper calculates C6 and f_damp in  a different way. The formula you presented was used since several decades ago (almost a century ago!), but the methods to calculate C6 and f_damp are what is different in the Becke-Johnson approach, vs the Grimme approach, vs the TS approach, etc.

Answer (score 20):

## 2004 (Yanai *et al.*): Range separation

Often, the source of DFT improvement comes from Hartree-Fock as is also obvious from the answer involving double hybrid functionals. So too it is with **range-separation**. The electron-electron Coulomb operator for the exchange contribution is separated into a short and long range contribution.

\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{r} = \frac{1-\text{erf}(\omega r)}{r} + \frac{\text{erf}(\omega r)}{r}
\end{equation}

where $\text{erf}$ is the standard error function. The $\omega$ parameter determines when to switch from using the short range part to the long range part. In this strategy the short range contribution is calculated using a density functional, and the long range contribution is calculated using HF. HF is good at this. What HF is not good at is correlation, but, there is a different functional for that. Right now, we are improving the electron-electron calculation.

The long range contribution from HF helps ensure that DFT overlocalization of charge separation is removed - notably yielding much improved excitation energies for charge-transfer states. **Overall: Range-separation helps solve self-interaction errors and improves excitation energies among other benefits.**

[1] T. Yanai, D.P. Tew and N.C. Handy, Chemical Physics Letters, 393, (1-3), 51-57 (2004)

Comment: I appreciate the homage to $\omega$B97-XD, but I wonder if you would mind shortening it perhaps to just one or the other and keeping it  to somewhere between 1-3 paragraphs like the dispersion corrections section? It would be nice if we could have about 20 compact, short summaries of recent milestones in DFT. It's also what both the asker and the bounty granter have asked for. Currently we are also having a discussion about whether or not to allow double-answers like this on our site. I fully appreciate all the time you took to write this full answer: Perhaps you give a link to longer version?

Comment: sure, but OP should use singular language too :)

Comment: It is very appreciated Charlie. As for the question asking for "Milestones" instead of a single "Milestone", I did not catch that, because I figured that after 20 people each give 1 milestone, there will be several milestones listed. However I will edit the question to make it even more clear and unambiguous!

Comment: Charlie: Your equation seems to be the same as Eq. 1 of this paper: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1564060, which according to Tyberius is the paper where "screened functionals" were first introduced.

Comment: Mine is from frank Jensen book. He attributes it to Tsuneda and Hiao (2014), but CAM-B3LYP was doing the general idea in 2004

Comment: The Heyd-Scuseria-Ernzerhof functional, which you link, is an inverse separation. It used HF for the short range where as my post is about using it as the long range. HSE is used for solid state calculations

Comment: Thanks for noting that difference. As for the origin of the idea to use HF for the long-range: the CAM-B3LYP paper you cited says that they got the idea from Tsuneda, but the Tsuneda paper was cited as "in press". Maybe it took from 2004-2014 for it to get pressed!

Comment: I have edited it to follow the format of all the other answers, and I also made it more compact (there wasn't a need for the "conclusion" heading to be just as big as the title heading of the answer! And there was an unnecessarily large gap between the references. Does Jensen's book need to be cited here? In the interest of providing useful but compact summaries, citations to tangentially related books might not be needed. I could have cited Jensen's book too I guess, and I guess all 7 of the answers here can end with a citation to that book! Doesn't seem necessary though :)

Comment: I've made some effort to make the this more compact (sticking to my 3-paragraph format, whereas before it was 5 paragraphs). The $r_{12}$ was only $r$ in the original papers, and it looks "cleaner" that way (fortunately in this case not being at the expense of ambiguity against $r_{34}$ or something like that). You're welcome to change it back if you are dissatisfied with these changes.

Comment: I'm curious if you might have some insight into this question? https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/647/5 It's been unanswered for 30 days, and the author said on Meta that he would put a bounty on it if someone answers it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot be of assistance on that question :(

Answer (score 19):

## 1993 (Becke): Hybrid Functionals

Axel D. Becke [introduced](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.464304) the adiabatic-connection model, which allows for mixing of DFT exchange and Fock-like exchange via the formula
$$
E_{\text{x}} = a \cdot E^{\text{HF}}_x + b \cdot E^{\text{GGA}}_x
$$
to obtain the exchange part of the exchange-correlation energy. Typically, one imposes $a+b = 1$, but some authors have sometimes abandoned the summation to $1$ or introduced exchange from the local density approximation (LDA a.k.a. Slater-Exchange) to the mix (B3LYP falls into this category).

Hybrids show improved performance over GGAs and meta-GGAs for the HOMO-LUMO gap, thermochemistry and excited states via time-dependent DFT. Especially for the latter, mixing parameters that are dependent on the electron-electron distance have yielded good results, leading to "long-range corrected" or "range-separated" hybrid functionals such as LC-PBE.

---

<sup>Technically, this is not more recent than 1996. Given the impact of hybrid functionals, I think it is proper to list this milestone regardless.</sup>

Comment: Becke's 1993 paper is already listed in the question.

Answer (score 18):

## 1995 (Casida): TD-DFRT

Time-Dependent Density Functional Response Theory is a linear response formulation of TDDFT for the calculation of excitation energies and corresponding transition amplitudes, that in turn allows to evaluate electronic spectra of molecular and condensed matter systems.

The time-dependent density functional theory (TDDFT) in the Kohn–Sham formalism is a set of differential equations for the time evolution of orbitals under the influence of an external field. However, in perturbation theory, TDDFT can be recast as an algebraic equation that describes the response in the frequency domain. Furthermore, instead of directly solving the response to an external field of particular frequency, one can calculate the resonant frequencies that correspond to the system's excitation energies (and to the poles of response functions).

This is achieved by the Casida equation, whose most general form is
$$
\pmatrix{A & B \\ -B^* & -A^* } \pmatrix{X_N \\ Y_N}
=
\omega_N \pmatrix{X_N \\ Y_N}
,
$$
where terms $A$, $B$ are the Hessians (also called coupling matrices), $\omega_N$ is the $N$-th excitation energy, and vectors $X_N$, $Y_N$ contain the corresponding transition amplitudes. The equation can be further simplified by considering the Tamm–Dancoff approximation (neglecting $B$) that can be added as a part of this direction of DFT development ([Hirata & Head-Gordon 1999](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009261499011495)).

For real orbitals and frequency-independent DFT kernel (part of the Hessian), the equation can alternatively be simplified by defining
$$
CZ_N = \omega_N^2 Z_N
,
$$
where $C=(A-B)^{1/2}(A+B)(A-B)^{1/2}$ and $Z_N=(A-B)^{1/2}(X_N-Y_N)$.
The Casida equation has the form of an eigenvalue equation with excitation energies being the eigenvalues.

The equation was introduced by [Casida in 1995](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789812830586_0005) and is now part of all major DFT codes and the primary DFT way of calculating excitation energies and excited state properties of wide range of systems.

Answer (score 13):

## 2005 (Bartlett): *ab initio* DFT

Basically one takes the xc functional from a wave function approach such as MBPT(2), CC, etc. and constructs an xc potential from them using density conditions or a functional derivatives approach. Summary of developments is best captured in the following article: "[Adventures in DFT by a wave function theorist](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5116338)."

Details on how to construct a local exchange potential from the HF exchange energy can found in the following article: "[Exact exchange treatment for molecules in finite-basis-set Kohn-Sham theory](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.83.5455)," while details about constructing the correlation potential from MBPT(2) energy can be found in the article title "[Ab initio density functional theory: The best of both worlds?](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1904585)"

Answer (score 12):

I would add some developments in TDDFT that came around 1996 and resonated only later such as:

- **the Casida equation** ([Casida 1995](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789812830586_0005)) that allows to calculate excitation energies and electronic spectra
- **the real-time TDDFT** ([Yabana & Bertsch 1996](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.54.4484)) a non-perturbative TDDFT technique in which the time-dependent Kohn–Sham equation is solved by direct propagation in time
- **the van Leeuwen theorem** ([van Leeuwen 1999](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.3863)) a generalization of the Runge–Gross theorem that also underpins the Kohn–Sham construction in TDDFT

Comment: Hi @LukasK, this is very useful information indeed! And welcome to the site! We hope to see much more of you here. Would you be able to pick one of them and explain it in the format that (most of) the other answers are in?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I can do it, and not just for one of them.

Comment: Preferrably you can pick one and focus on it. That's what I would prefer anyway. That's also what I did (I could have written several answers here but chose to focus on one).

Comment: OK, so the Casida equation it is (most citations, most widespread, before 1996 but not on the original list).

Comment: I think it's ok to add something from  before 1996, if it's not already on the list.

Answer (score 10):

Most chemists' point of view could be condensed as follows:

**Implementation of DFT in Gaussian** (Pople et al, 1992)
LDAs and GGAs were implemented in Gaussian 92/DFT by Pople, Gill and Johnson [Chem Phys Lett 199, 557 (1992)].

**DFT better than ab initio** (Johnson et al, 1993)
BLYP was found to yield more accurate equilibrium geometries, dipole moments, harmonic vibrational frequencies and atomization energies than ab initio methods, using the 6-31G* basis set [J Chem Phys 98, 5612 (1993)].

**B3LYP** (Stephens et al, 1994)
The B3LYP functional was proposed based on Becke's earlier suggestion, where the correlation functional was just changed from PW91 to LYP.

This culminated in the infamous B3LYP/6-31G* model chemistry...

Comment: +1. Especially for the reference to the under-appreciated paper by Stephens. As for DFT being better than *ab initio* methods, maybe it would be help to list the specific methods that DFT was tested to be better than, because I'm sure it's not better than *ab initio* methods such as FCI and CCSDTQ!

Comment: @NikeDattani even FCI is not that good in 6-31G* which was the basis they used....

Answer (score 9):

## 1997 (Marzari & Vanderbilt): MLWF

- These methods enable a more qualitative view of the electron density by projecting the Bloch wavefunctions into localized Wannier functions [1], which is especially useful when it comes to transition metal systems, but not limited to these.
- This description enables DFT practitioners to "talk" to the modelling community, since now we can approximate the physics and chemistry of the system in terms of orbitals.
- Two major milestones are the description of the maximally localized Wannier functions (MLWF) method by Marzari and Vanderbilt [2] and its community open-source implementation as `Wannier90` [3].
- There are still ongoing work to perfect the method (such as alternative projection criteria), and to apply it to study other (more *exotic*) material systems. For instance, recently it has been used to describe the effective physics of the spin liquid candidate $\alpha$-$\ce{RuCl_3}$ [4].

**References:**

[1] G.H. Wannier, *Phys. Rev.* **52**, 191 (1937), doi:[10.1103/PhysRev.52.191](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.52.191)
[2] N. Marzari & D. Vanderbilt, *Phys. Rev. B* **56**, 12847 (1997), doi:[10.1103/PhysRevB.56.12847](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.56.12847); N. Marzari *et al.*, *Rev. Mod. Phys.* **84**, 1419 (2002), doi:[10.1103/RevModPhys.84.1419](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.84.1419)
[3] A.A. Mostofi *et al.*, *Comput. Phys. Commun.* **178**, 685 (2008), doi:[10.1016/j.cpc.2007.11.016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2007.11.016); A.A. Mostofi *et al.*, *Comput. Phys. Commun.* **185**, 2309 (2014), doi:[10.1016/j.cpc.2014.05.003](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2014.05.003); G. Pizzi *et al.*, *J. Phys. Cond. Mat.* **32**(16), 165902 (2020), doi:[10.1088/1361-648X/ab51ff](https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-648X/ab51ff)
[4] C. Eichstaedt *et al.*, *Phys. Rev. B* **100**, 075110 (2019), doi:[10.1103/PhysRevB.100.075110](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.100.075110)

Comment: Great answer, and I gave you +1, but there's a lot of edits that I made to make this answer look more like the general format of most of our other answers. Spacing for the references, use of \ce{ } in your MathJaX code, font size for the header, etc. Please take note!

Comment: It should be noted that "maximally localized" is ambiguous; the Pipek-Mezey Wannier functions are also maximally localized. See https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jctc.6b00809

Comment: @SusiLehtola I agree, there are multiple ways to define "maximally localized", and the Marzari/Vanderbilt paper was the first one to propose a criterion. I personally use the criterion by Anisimov & Kozhevnikov: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.72.075125

Answer (score 8):

## 2020 Furness et al: r$^2$SCAN functional

The [SCAN functional](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1192/5) is the most recent meta-GGA functional constructed from first principles, which satisfies all known bounds. However, SCAN is also numerically pathological: getting converged energies requires huge quadrature grids, and constructing pseudopotentials is difficult. This motivated the construction of the regularized SCAN (rSCAN) functional of Bartók and Yates in [J. Chem. Phys. 150, 161101 (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5094646), which eliminated the numerical instabilities in SCAN.

The r$^2$SCAN functional, published in [J. Phys. Chem. Lett. 11,  8208 (2020)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpclett.0c02405) builds upon rSCAN, but restores some of the exact constraints of SCAN. In addition to being numerically stable and thereby faster than SCAN, r$^2$SCAN has been found to yield spectacular performance, see e.g. [recent work by Grimme and coworkers](https://chemrxiv.org/articles/preprint/r2SCAN-3c_An_Efficient_Swiss_Army_Knife_Composite_Electronic-Structure_Method/13333520/2)

Answer (score 7):

## 2001 (Taylor *et al.*): DFT+NEGF

- Combining density functional theory (NEGF) with nonequilibrium Green's function method (NEGF),  a self-consistent first-principles technique for modeling quantum transport properties of atomic and molecular scale nanoelectronic devices under external bias potentials is reported.
- Implementation packages: [QuantumATK](https://docs.quantumatk.com/index.html), [Nanodcal](http://www.nanoacademic.ca:8080/nchannel.jsp?id=2) and [Questaal](https://www.questaal.org/) ...
- Reference: [Phys.Rev.B 63, 245407](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.63.245407)

This paper has been chosen as one of [Physical Review B 50th Anniversary Milestones:](https://journals.aps.org/prb/50th)

The following is the comments:

> Over the last few decades, there has been an explosion in the realm of nanotechnology, nanodevices, and nanomaterials, where anything ‘nano’ has become part of the condensed matter and materials physics lexicon. As has often been restated, this is due to the great potential for technological applications. However, this potential produced the need for a better understanding of the fundamental physics at the atomic scale not just for molecular modeling, but for device and application purposes as well. In the early 2000s, the use of density functional theory (DFT) and ab initio modeling continued to revolutionize the way we understand materials. Two outstanding PRB papers reported on the incursion of DFT into the arena of quantum electron transport properties by means of nonequilibrium Green’s functions. They helped pave the way for the advancement of device modeling at the atomistic level.

Comment: Can you please follow the format of the other answers?

Comment: This a good start to a couple different answers, but ideally we would prefer each answer to address one topic.

Comment: @NikeDattani I have updated my answers. That is the correct format?  If the answer is no, please help me to edit the answer to the correct format.

Comment: I would recommend keeping this answer and removing the other two. We highly prefer that a user doesn't answer several times on the same question, and instead of spending time on 3 topics, spends 3x the amount of time on 1 topic. Since the other two answers are just copying and pasting abstracts from other people's papers, I would recommend to keep this one :)

Comment: @NikeDattani [What are some recent developments in density functional theory?]. This is the question. I agree OFTDFT can't be thought of as the recent development. But my other two answers [citations > 500] are no problem. I just cut the abstract to explain what they have done and cited the paper. PS: Is the style of [each answer to address one topic] reasonable? I doubt it.

Comment: @Jack You say that you doubt that it's reasonable for us to have each answer addressing just one topic: You are free to express that opinion here: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/5 (there have been some arguments for following the [tag:one-topic-per-answer] format (for example if 3 topics were in one answer, are we upvoting because we like OFDFT, or because we like DFT+NEGF or because we like the answer about band-gaps? What if someone likes OFDFT but does NOT like the other two, how do they split the vote)? We also don't 3 different comment chains on one answer.

Comment: I gave you +1 on this answer now, but I see that other people gave you -1 on all three, and a moderator deleted your other two answers. I did not tell anyone to do either of those things (I was not even at my computer for the last 7 hours), it was just that others did not like what you did. Also the mod that deleted your answers didn't downvote you (Tyberius has 1 total downvote). In general if you're just going to be copying and pasting an abstract, it's probably better to just write a link to the paper in a comment. You can't earn rep for posting an abstract of someone else's paper :)

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks for your suggestions. I will try my best to follow the rules of your community.  I agree that you delete my OFDFT answer. But I will edit my other answer related to the band-gap problem, it is one of the most recent improvements in the DFT field.

Answer (score 6):

## 2014 (Gagliardi): MPCDFT

Multiconfiguration Pair-Density Functional Theory (MC-PDFT) is a theoretical framework that combines multiconfigurational wave functions with a generalization of density functional theory.
As the reference wavefunction is multiconfigurational rather than being a single Slater determinant, it has the advantage that it can describe strongly correlated systems, bond dissociations, and electronic excitations. This requires a new type of density functionals (functionals of the total
density, its gradient, and the on-top pair density) that can be obtained by translating conventional density functionals of the spin densities. As the on-top pair density is an element of the two-particle density matrix, this goes beyond the Hohenberg−Kohn theorem that refers only to the one-particle density.

**References:**

1. G. Li Manni, R. K. Carlson, S. Luo, D. Ma, J. Olsen, D. G. Truhlar, L. Gagliardi, [Multiconfiguration pair-density functional theory.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ct500483t) J. Chem. Theory Comput. 10, 3669–3680 (2014).
2. L. Gagliardi, D. G. Truhlar, G. L. Manni, R. K. Carlson, C. E. Hoyer, J. L. Bao, [Multiconfiguration pair-density functional theory: A new way to treat strongly correlated systems.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.accounts.6b00471) Acc. Chem. Res. 50, 66–73 (2017).

Comment: +1. Welcome to our community, and thank you for contributing your excellent answer here! We hope to see much more of you !!! I had actually asked Laura Gagliardi and Giovanni Li Manni to write something about MPCDFT here, but they were both very busy during our COVID-filled summer!

Answer (score 4):

## 2016: Reproducibility of DFT calculations (Lejaeghere *et al*)

Lejaeghere et al.$^1$ compared the calculated values for the equation of states for 71 elemental crystals from 15 different widely used DFT codes employing 40 different potentials. They defined a single parameter, Δ, which allowed the comparison of EOS calculated with different codes, giving a simple route to evaluating the reproducibility of DFT. Δ was defined as the root-mean-square energy difference between the equations of state of the two codes, averaged over all crystals in a purely elemental benchmark set.

The key result from this paper is that modern DFT codes now achieve a precision which is comparable to  high-precision experiments; a delta value which is better than 1 meV/atom. This precision applies across various basis sets: plane waves, augmented plane waves, and numerical orbitals. It also applies to all-electron, PAW, and both ultra-soft and norm-conserving pseudopotential calculations.
The work demonstrates that the precision of DFT implementations can be determined and also shows that the pseudopotential approach using recent libraries are precise in comparison with all-electron results.

The summary table from the paper is shown below; the numbers given are the RMS value for Δ across all 71 elements and colour indicates overall reliability.

[image]

**References:**

1. [Lejaeghere, Kurt, et al. "Reproducibility in density functional theory calculations of solids." Science 351.6280 (2016](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/351/6280/aad3000)).
2. https://molmod.ugent.be/deltacodesdft
3. https://davidbowler.github.io/AtomisticSimulations/blog/dft-reliability

Answer (score 3):

## Solving the band-gap problem at DFT level (2008)

- To obtain the correct band-gap in semiconductor physics and materials science is very important for device applications, such as charge transport and optical absorption. It is well known that DFT with PBE exchange-correlation functional will underestimate the band-gap of semiconducting materials. Currently, some methods based on DFT have been proposed, such as hybrid functional and GW approximation. Unfortunately, these schemes are computationally prohibitive for large systems, especially when the spin-orbit coupling becomes important. How to solve the band-gap problem at the DFT level cost is the core problem of this field.  This following cited paper tries to explain the failure of conventional exchange-correlation functional from the viewpoint of the fractional charge, which can be considered as one of the most important developments in recent years.
- Ref: [Localization and Delocalization Errors in Density Functional Theory and Implications for Band-Gap Prediction.](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.100.146401)

Comment: To my understanding also the exact xc functional underestimates the bandgap. See, e.g., https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.51.1884