# Difference between Van der Waals (DFT-D and DFT-D3) corrections in ab-initio calculations

Tags: density-functional-theory, kohn-sham, dispersion-correction

In Kohn-Sham DFT calculations, Van der Waals corrections are often implemented in the structure optimization calculations because the typical functionals such as LDA and GGA are found to not treat long-range dispersion forces faithfully. But even in the context of Van der Waals corrections, there are some options such as the DFT-D and DFT-D3 schemes (refer [quantum espresso's documentation - under 'vdw-corr' tag](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#idm592)).

What is the difference between these two corrections? Also, is it possible to conclude which one is more suited for a certain application?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you mention, there are **many** empirical dispersion corrections for density functional theory.

Generally, the term "DFT-D" refers to a generic dispersion-corrected density functional calculation, regardless of the specific method used for the dispersion correction used.

The D3 dispersion model is a specific dispersion correction method and is now something of a family, started by Grimme's 2010 article:
"A consistent and accurate ab initio parametrization of density functional dispersion correction (DFT-D) for the 94 elements H-Pu" [*J. Chem. Phys.* 132, 154104 (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3382344)

In most cases, it's recommended to use Becke-Johnson damping - D3BJ:
[*J. Comput. Chem.*, 32: 1456-1465 (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.21759)

There have been a few efforts to improve these:

- D3M - [J. Phys. Chem. Lett. 2016, 7, 12, 2197–2203](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpclett.6b00780)
- D3(op) - [J. Chem. Theory Comput. 2017, 13, 5, 2043–2052](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.7b00176)
- D4 - [J. Chem. Phys. 150, 154122 (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5090222)

There are a *wide* variety of other methods, particularly those working to add many-body dispersion. Grimme wrote a review, although obviously it's been an active field:

"Dispersion-Corrected Mean-Field Electronic Structure Methods" [Chem. Rev. 2016, 116, 9, 5105–5154](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.chemrev.5b00533)

Comment: +1. We have a similar question that remains un-answered:
https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/63/which-dispersion-corrections-in-dft-exist-and-how-do-they-compare. I wonder what we can do about it: Is it something that you think can be answered without too much difficulty, or is its broadness (asking for a comparison for *all* dispersion corrections) something we should encourage the user to change (i.e. pick a few dispersion corrections and ask for comparison between those)?